# Files.readAllLines() does not read all characters correctly

Tags: java, java-io

I have a simple text file which includes only one character which is '≤'. Nothing else. This file has UTF-8 encoding.
When I read this file using the method Files.readAllLines(), the character is shown as a question mark '?'

```
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(file, "f.txt"));
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fw);) {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(deProp.toPath());
            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.println();
            }
```

In my example I am trying to print the line to the console and to a new file. In both cases a question mark is shown instead.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Is the problem in your console, or in that `f.txt`? I notice that you don't specify a character set in `FileWriter`, which means it uses the platform default, which is not necessarily UTF-8.

Comment: Yes actually the problem was in the console and I changed the way of the writing to the file with OutputStreamWriter and set the Charset to UTF-8. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Files.readAllLines(path)`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) already uses UTF-8 (see the linked documentation). If you're using the `Files.readAllLines(path, charset)` variant, well, pass `UTF-8` as the charset, of course (for example by using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Assuming you're using either the short version or passing UTF-8, then the error lies not with java, but with your setup.

Either the file doesn't contain ≤ in UTF-8, or you're printing it in java to a place that doesn't show such symbols (for example, because your font doesn't have it, and uses ? as the placeholder symbol for 'I do not have this symbol in my font file'; it's more usually a box symbol), or you're sending the output someplace that incorrectly presumes that what is sent is not UTF-8.

Comment: You are right. It seems that the Eclipse console didn't show this character correctly. I replaced the FileWriter with
 OutputStreamWriter writer =
              new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(file, "f.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), so it works now :)

Comment: Ah. Don't use FileWriter; it uses 'platform default encoding' which is not something you'd ever want to use, pretty much. The problem doesn't lie with eclipse either. It's that.

Answer (score 0):

The static method of File class e.i

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path) throws IOException
```

is read all the lines from a file. The bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the UTF-8 charset. This method invoking equivalent to evaluating the expression:

```
 Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

It may be possible that the file contains some garbage or something out of format of UTF-8 charset. Check the text inside files once manually :p